# Changind Telerik Skin according to page sizes

Tags: telerik, mobile-devices, page-size

How could we change the Telerik Skin according to the size of the window or the type of the reading revice?

Example: If the user is on a computer, i want to render the "Default" skin but if it is on a mobile device, i want to render the "MetroTouch" skin.

Is there some way to do that dynamically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can detect the device screen size via the Telerik Device Detection framework and set the desired skin according to its dimensions. See these resources for more information:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/detection-framework.html
http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/device-detection-framework.aspx
http://demos.telerik.com/responsive-web-design-aspnet/